# How to call set of code after a certain div loaded in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I was trying to call a set of line of code (JS) after a certain condition like I want to do some manipulation on a DOM element after a div is loaded.
I have tried something like this

```
$("#divId").ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

PS:-  The div is loaded on an AJAX call

Comment: provide more code .. where is your ajax code .. and where you called the code above??  and what is  $("#divId").ready() expected to do?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef  AJAX renders a table and I have to do some manipulations on columns, like which to show and which to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all tries finally I come to this most feasible solution: -

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  alert("all done !")
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**How to call set of code after a certain div loaded**
**PS:- The div is loaded on an AJAX call**

you can call you code in `Ajax .complete() event`.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that in the AJAX success block too, but I am looking for a specific answer so that I can perform some operations when a DOM element is completely rendered, like .ready() or .load() on document. Can we do something like .ready() works on any of the DOM element. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

after div is loaded via ajax you can use in ajax success callback function

```
Div.html('your html code here').promise().done(function(){ // you can use it after append() as well
    // code here
});
```

It may help